# Use Action Cable to reflect changes in one project occurred due to another project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am trying to implement `Action Cable`. I have previously worked with it though only the basics. I am now working on a project where the admin and the client section are two different projects. The database for both is same of-course.

What i want is that as soon as the `User` (from the `Client-Side Project`) texts the admin, it should (text) be displayed to the `Admin` (In the `Admin side Project`) in real time, i.e without refreshing the page.

[How to use ActionCable as API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320791/how-to-use-actioncable-as-api) gave me ideas but i'm not sure as how i should move forward with it.

Another idea that i had was to implement `action cable` in the `Admin` Project and call it in a `action` of a `controller`. Now when the text is created in the `client` project, i'll call this action (in the controller of admin project; how i have not yet figured out and yet working on it). This way the `Action Cable` will reflect changes in the `Admin`.

I don't know if this approach is correct or there's another way.

I'll be grateful for any guidance. Thanks.

P.S: Let me know if this confusing and messy. I'll give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need is to have the admin user subscribe to a channel only used by admins and at the same time have the messages being submitted by users broadcast to that specific channel.

Something along the lines of this:

**channels/admin_chat_channel.rb**

```
class AdminChatChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    if current_user.is_admin?
      stream_from "admin_chat_channel"  
    end
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def update
  end
end
```

I'm using coffeescript in this example. I can convert it to js if you prefer.

**javascripts/channels/admin_chat.coffee**

```
(document).ready ->
  App.merge_requests = App.cable.subscriptions.create {
    channel: "AdminChatChannel"
  },
  connected: ->
    console.log 'Admin Chat Connected'

  disconnected: ->
    console.log 'Admin Chat Disconnected'

  received: (message) ->
    $('.some_chat_div').append(message)
```

On the controller in which you will be receiving the submitted messages you just need to broadcast the message:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "admin_chat_channel", message
```