# Rails ActionCable Connection(Server) with NodeJs(Client)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, websocket, client-server, actioncable

I want to create a connection between rails `ActionCable` which will act as `Server` and `NodeJs` as `Client`.

This is my code in `connection.rb` file.

```
 # app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
 module ApplicationCable
   class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :uuid

    def connect
     self.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
    end
  end
 end
```

This is code of my channel.

```
 # app/channels/socket_connection_channel.rb
 class SocketConnectionChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
   stream_from "socket_connect"
  end

  def speak
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("socket_connect",
                             message: "Connected")
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
   end

 end
```

And this is NodeJs code in `server.js` file

```
   const WebSocket = require('ws');

   const ws = new WebSocket('ws://0.0.0.0:3001/cable');

   ws.on('open', function open() {
     ws.send(JSON.stringify({'data': 'Sample Data'}));
   });

    ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
     console.log(data);
     });

   ws.on('socket_connected', function incoming(data) {
      console.log('socket');
    });
```

When I run the server `node server`

```
  {"type":"welcome"}
  {"type":"ping","message":1497487145}
  {"type":"ping","message":1497487148}
  {"type":"ping","message":1497487151}
```

and on rails  server displays the following logs

```
     Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-15 
    02:39:02 +0200
      Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
      Registered connection (5db66385-0923-4633-8837-ba957fc0a7f5)
      Received unrecognized command in {"data"=>"Sample Data"}
```

What I want to achieve is that `node server` will make the Websocket connection on rails `ActionCable` and subscribe to `SocketConnect` Channel and will `transmit` the data to Rails server via this channel.

I have found some examples of `chat` application on rails action server where the `client` and `server` both are on smae `rails` platform. But, I haven't found any example where `client` is on separate palatform than server.

But, I am unable to find any method to `Subscribe` for this channel and make a stable connection on both ends to transmit data and I also don't know how to get data from this request.

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Sending subscribe and setting identifier for socketchannel is important point.

## rails

```
# app/channels/socket_connection_channel.rb
 class SocketConnectionChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
   @uuid = params[:uuid]
   stop_all_streams
   stream_from "socket_connect_#{@uuid}"
   logger.info ">>> Subscribed #{@uuid}!"
  end

  def speak
    logger.info "[ActionCable] received message : #{data['message']}" 
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "socket_connect_#{@uuid}", message: "#{data['message']} from server"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
   end

 end
```

## node.js

```
var App = {};

App.sendmessage = function(send) {
  data = {
    message : send,
    action : "speak"
  };
  message = {
    command: "message",
    identifier: JSON.stringify(App.param),
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  };    
  App.ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
}

App.connect_server = function() {         
  const WebSocket = require('ws');
  App.ws = new WebSocket('ws://0.0.0.0:3001/cable', ["actioncable-v1-json", "actioncable-unsupported"]);

  App.param = {channel: "SocketConnectionChannel", uuid: guid()};

  App.ws.on('open', function open() {
    data = {
      command: "subscribe",
      identifier: JSON.stringify(App.param)
    }
    App.ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  });  
  App.ws.on('message', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
  });
  function guid() {
   function s4() {
     return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
   }
   return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
  }
}
App.connect_server();
```

## node.js

```
App.sendmessage("Hello world");
```

https://github.com/mwalsher/actioncable-js is also helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I write this code in separate `node.js` file and run server with
`node node.js` command it shows me following error.


`(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { window.App = {}`
`ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Comment: window is not necessary. Just do it => "var App = {};"

Comment: after declaring `var App = {};` I am still getting error `window is not defined`. 
I assume it is associated with `HTML`/`DOM` object. But I am using only js file to run `server`. I don't know how can I initialize `window`.

Comment: Thanks. You are awesome. It worked :) .    Can you please share any reference or source where all the details/usage of other methods/functions is given.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320791/how-to-use-actioncable-as-api. It will be more helpful. :D