# Rails Websocket and different implementations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

We are in the process of creating a Rails application that uses a 3rd party websocket API (not sure what language the 3rd party uses).  I understand the concept of Websockets and it's purpose and would be a perfect fit for our high transactional application.  Our application uses a Rails API backend and a React front end.

To give an idea of our application, we basically track 15k+ different accounts that are always changing with multiple transactions per second that we show in close to real time (polled once per second) to the respective user who is logged and has access to see the ledger and balance.  Currently we use normal REST api to pull ledger history (which is being polled).

Unfortunately most websocket/ActionCable examples that I've googled are closed looped chat programs (open 2 browsers -- hit same web page). I'm unable to find anything that would lead me in the right direction for that we're trying to do (see below).

Anyway, our ideal situation is we would like to continue to use our Rails API we developed and switch from polled API calls to websockets for our ledgers.  We would like to keep track of the data from the 3rd party (and transforming it for our clients) before sending it to our clients (eventually using our own future websocket implementation).  So, is this even possible with Rails API to connect to a 3rd party websocket api on the backend?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320791/how-to-use-actioncable-as-api#36120630

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of connecting to a non-ActionCable (3rd party) websocket from the backend.  This is shows how a client that doesn't use ActionCable can implement using the ActionCable protocol from their own client.

Comment: thanks a lot. which client are you planning to use? I would like to read some of their documentation

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby   it seems to be working so far (the client part of it)

Comment: nice. I never used faye. I always thought learning actioncable was the best choice but it is incredible that they don't provide an easy way to implement api